# How to temporarily suppress programs from startup folder in Windows 7 without changing the configuration?

Tags: windows-7, login

I'm logging in to my Windows 7 box, and *just this one time* I want to prevent the programs in my Startup folder from running; perhaps because they're time-consuming, and I'm in a hurry; perhaps because there is somebody watching over my shoulder.

How can I do this?

I believe that in some previous versions of Windows, you could do it by holding down the Shift key after entering your name and password

Please don't answer with anything like "Login and ...", "remove", "disable" or "msconfig", because I don't want to change my configuration at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my research, ability to bypass startup items was removed from Windows Vista and Windows 7, But recently i found that Microsoft release some hot fixes to update or add this functionality. (I would like to mention that i didn't check that).  Below are links to to Microsoft KB

- [The Shift key on a USB keyboard does not override the automatic logon setting on a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526967)
- [SHIFT does not override the automatic logon setting on a computer that is running a 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2003, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977534)

Comment: Sathya: Well, the links you provided don't directly address my question, but they do make it look like Microsoft probably took away the functionality I remembered.  Thanks.