# Stop or pause Windows startup programs during boot?

Tags: windows, boot, performance, process, task-manager

Is there an application or program that can **stop or pause startup programs during boot**? For example using a hotkey to pause the startup queue temporarily or simply stop it altogether.

**Note:** This is different from selectively disabling startup programs in the **task manager** or **msconfig**. Rather this is a live monitor during boot that can pause or stop the queue **at any given time**.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to SUPPRESS programs from startup folder (Windows 7)?](http://superuser.com/questions/458912/how-to-suppress-programs-from-startup-folder-windows-7)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question is about **stopping or pausing** the current startup list at any time rather than **bypassing** it.

Comment: As the author of the "How to SUPPRESS ..." question, I agree with Gabriel -- this is not the same question. (RobH's answer, below, is an _answer_ to my question, although, unfortunately, not a correct one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LaunchMeNot](https://launchmenot.codeplex.com/) is the only program I have found capable of canceling startup programs during boot.

The program has an autostart feature "Autolaunch" which loads a custom list of programs, if you import all the startup programs to that list it will stop loading them whenever you need, no pause however.

Alternatively there are programs that can delay startup programs like [WinPatrol](http://www.winpatrol.com/download.html) but awkwardly enough don't offer the stop/cancel feature.

Comment: [Jockersoft Startup Delayer](http://www.jockersoft.com/english/startupdelayer_index.php) has also a feature to cancel startup programs during boot, the behavior is similar to LaunchMeNot.

Answer (score -1):

To disable the startup list on a one time basis, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down while Windows is booting up.

Comment: This function has been removed in Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: Typical Microsoft, removing useful features like that.